# update multiple fields via filter for a django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have defined the following model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=26,unique=True)
    coins = models.IntegerField()
    points = models.IntegerField()
    language = models.CharField(max_length=3)
```

Now I would like to run a filter query and update coins and points for all users matching my query.

However, I must have gotten something wrong, since field values won't get updated this way (I don't receive error messages):

```
User.objects.filter(language='en', points__gte=score).update(coins='100', points='10')
```

What is the correct way to update the fields for my selection?

Comment: Does your `filter()` return any records?

Comment: yes, my filter returns records because in fact I am using the same filter in the context of a for loop to send notifications to users and that works

Comment: The statement is correct and should update all objects in the queryset. There must be an error somewhere else. It is by the way very bad idea to name your class `User`, because this is already reserved by Django and you never know what side effects can happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the **statements seem to be correct**, but should pass `integers` instead of `strings`.

You can try this way:

```
users=User.objects.filter(language='en', points__gte=score)
```

Now,

```
for user in users:
    user.coins = 100
    user.points=10
    user.save()
```

There is **already a `bultin` model named `User`** so you should try avoiding it as a model name.

Comment: No you shouldn't avoid model name clashes. It's what python imports separate. App labels do the same for django apps. Referencing an external model is therefore always done by 'app_label.ModelName'. In fact, if you **override** the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is preferable to keep the model name 'User' to indicate it's the project's User model where django.contrib.auth is concerned.

Comment: @Melvyn, But I told him to avoid for the confusion, not that he can not use it. There is a difference in saying `avoid` and `don't use`.

Comment: There's no good reason to avoid it. Why would I name Address MyCoolAppAddress and another app would call their Address ThatCoolAppAddress. They're addresses. Need'm both? Alias them.

Comment: There are very good reasons to avoid confusion, they are called best practices. It is not about MyAdress and TheirAddress, it is about classes defined by the framework and your classes. Using `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in the settings.py is though the recommended way. You can call your class `User`, because you obviously know what are you doing. Beginners should try to avoid any pitfalls.

Comment: @cezar, Thanks for that comment.

Answer (score 0):

You use `update` in a right way. But there might eventually a little problem in the following issue.

Your model has the fields:

```
coins = models.IntegerField()
points = models.IntegerField()
```

Do you notice something? They are integer fields.
Maybe you can try your statement again with this slight change:

```
User.objects.filter(
    language='en', points__gte=score
).update(
    coins=100, points=10
)
```

Pass integers and not strings!